# Выделение текста закругленной, повернутой тенью

Tags: css, border, box-shadow

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать подобное через CSS, используя `<span>`
Закруглить получается, но не получается повернуть и поднять, так как обрезается верхняя часть.
[image]

Сейчас получается так:

```
span {
    font-size: 30px;
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 55px 0 0 #FBD713;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 0em;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вопрос должен быть закрыт, так как на [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь [Stack Overflow на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Stack Overflow - не площадка по решению задач, тут помогают разобраться в Вашей проблеме. Выложите свои наработки и посмотрим.

Comment: Тень не может быть трансформирована без трансформации самого элемента.

Comment: Да, спасибо за разъяснение, попробую использовать псевдоэлемент.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну это просто как вариант. Псевдоэлемент выступает в роли той самой жёлтой фоновой линии. Этот псевдоэлемент закругляем и с помощью `transform` располагаем и поворачиваем как нам нужно.

```css
.decorated {
  font-size: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.decorated:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -2px) rotate(-3deg);
  background-color: #f9d21a;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<span class="decorated">It is interesting!</span>
```